# How is an object instantiated within a "with" block?

Tags: python

I have done the following in a python interpreter (2.7.13):

```
>>> class test:
...     def __init__(self):
...             print "Object has been constructed!"
...     def __enter__(self):
...             print "Entering with"
...     def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
...             print "Exiting with"
... 
>>> 
>>> t1 = test()
Object has been constructed!
>>> print t1
<__main__.test instance at 0x7fed5383e3b0>
>>> 
>>> with test() as t1:
...     print "Inside 'with' block"
...     print t1
... 
Object has been constructed!
Entering with
Inside 'with' block
None
Exiting with
```

My question is: why does `print` outputs `none` within the `with` block ? Object seems to be instantiated by `with` (at least, we can see that there is a call to the constructor), but t1 does not seem to exist within the namespace. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It prints `None` because `__enter__` return `None` (implicitly).

Consider following sample:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Object has been constructed!"
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Entering with"
        return 5
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print "Exiting with"

with test() as t1:
    assert t1 == 5
```

`AssertionError` is not raised, therefore we know `t1` is equal to 5.

In general, value assigned to `something` in `with ctx_mgr as something:` can be anything, not strictly `ctx_mgr`. If it had to be `ctx_mgr`, `with ... as ...` construct would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

you need to return `self` (or any other object depending on your needs) in your context manager method `__enter__`; the result of this function is assigned to `as`:

```
class test:
    ...
    def __enter__(self):
            print( "Entering with")
            return self
    ...
```

how it works in described in [python context manager types](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types).

Comment: Thank you that clears things up. If I understand correctly then, t1 has type ` None`  unless `__enter__` returns ` self`. That makes sense.

Comment: python functions that end witout hitting a `return` statement implicitly return `None`. `__enter__` can return anything you want.